# Pls help me modify this sentence

Tags: american-english

So he had to end his football career in getting a neck injury during match in 2007

Comment: Please start getting the message that questions of this form do not belong here. We are not a proofreading service. Please also start having the courtesy to at least spell out "please". Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not like starting a sentence with "so" but I suggest

> ...so he had to end his football career due to a neck injury he sustained during a match in 2007.

or

> ...so in 2007 he had to end his football career due to a neck injury he sustained during a match.

depending on when the injury was and when he ended his career

Answer (score 1):

Yes, choice of preposition is not easy here. In a real sense, it was the neck injury and not the player that/who 'ended his career', so a rephrasing is probably better here:

> In a football match in 2007 he sustained a neck injury so serious it
>   ended his career.